# React drop down

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

```
<TextField
    // autoFocus
    margin="dense"
    // id="name"
    select
    label="Majorhead ID"
    type="text"
    fullWidth
    onChange={(event) => {
        this.setState({majorhead: event.target.value});
        }}
        value={this.state.majorhead}
        InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
        root: this.props.classes.textfieldLabel,
        },
        }}
    >
        {majorhead.all_majorhead.map((row1) => (
            <MenuItem value={{id:row1._id,name:row1.name}} key={row1.majorhead_id}>
                {row1.name}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
</TextField>
```

Look to this code and the images help me to achieve it.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49XdT.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR3mp.png)
Even after choosing the desired value I can't see the chosen option viewed. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value for `MenuItems` like `value={row1._id}` ?

```
const handleChange = id => {
    // Here you can get the complete object of the id.
    const targetObject = majorhead.all_majorhead.filter(item => item._id === id)
    this.setState({majorhead_id: id});
}

<Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={this.state.majorhead_id}
    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value)}
>
    {majorhead.all_majorhead.map((row1) => (
        // Value should not be object
        <MenuItem value={row1._id} key={row1.majorhead_id}>
            {row1.name}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
```

Comment: need to send a dictionary stuff in value like value={{id:row1._id,name:row1.name}}. need to have 2 values instead of a single string

Comment: If you need the the value for submit or anything else, handle it outside MenuItem value. See the edit